# Black outline around map polygons (IE)

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary

This only happens in some IE's. Here: http://animactions.ca/Animactions/volet_entreprise.php

You may notice that when you click and drag on one of the circles, you will get something similar to this: http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/7578/errorra.png

I cannot figure it out. Here is my image map:

```
<p class="style2">
  <map id="FPMap0" name="FPMap0">
  <area coords="405, 8, 375, 10, 353, 13, 322, 30, 317, 48, 327, 69, 344, 75, 370, 84, 401, 86, 428, 81, 454, 69, 466, 56, 468, 37, 452, 19, 419, 9" href="le_developpement_des_equipes_de_travail.php" shape="poly" style="outline:0" target="_blank" />
  <area coords="95, 164, 65, 166, 43, 174, 21, 186, 16, 206, 27, 225, 48, 237, 76, 241, 99, 241, 129, 236, 151, 228, 165, 214, 167, 194, 154, 177, 130, 168, 105, 165" href="le_developpement_operationnel.php" shape="poly" style="outline:0" target="_blank" />
  <area coords="138, 17, 115, 7, 95, 8, 63, 8, 41, 20, 21, 35, 23, 60, 42, 74, 77, 83, 117, 86, 144, 76, 164, 62, 173, 40, 156, 21, 137, 12" href="coaching_strategique_de_cadre.php" shape="poly" style="border-width:0" target="_blank" />
  </map>
  <img alt="services entreprise" height="258" src="Images/service_ent.PNG" width="490" usemap="#FPMap0" /></p>
```

I really hope someone can figure this out because I'v tried everything...

Thanks

Comment: Well i had this same problem... you might wanna refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030444/unwanted-border-around-the-image-map-area/9108366#9108366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be the `outline` of the coordinates. I'm not sure which element precisely you need to target to remove it, but if you try:

```
p.style2 * :active,
p.style2 * :focus {outline: none; }
```

That should remove them, I think.

Comment: It's css, so ideally put it into your linked stylesheet. Failing that, you can put it into the `<head>` of your `(x)html` file, after any other linked stylesheets. Bear in mind that if it's in the html itself then it needs to be replicated across every page that suffers from the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, solved it by applying `onfocus="this.blur();` inside area element..

It's too late for you but might help others..:)

Thanks,
Sundip