# Unwanted border around the image map area

Tags: html, css, image, maps

I am using an Image map with a circular area. The problem is I get an unwanted border around the area in IE7. This border doesn't appear in FF and Chrome and also in IE8/IE9.

I tried adding border="0" to the image, css properties for the anchors i.e

```
a{ 
border:none !important;
outline:none !important;
}
```

but didn't work.

I also tried adding the IE fix onfocus="blur();" in the  tag. This solved the issue in IE but then FF got the border now. 
Searched a lot and came through this fix which said it will fix the issue for FF when IE fix is used.

```
#parent_div *:active, #parent_div *:focus { overflow-x:hidden; outline:none; }
```

But sadly even this didn't work. I am using FF 9.0.1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 866 rep and 0% accepted answers?! Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yes...coz there's no one solution. Check all the answers for workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

```
img{border:none;}
```

and this is the fix for ie versions

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
function correctPNG() // correctly handle PNG transparency in Win IE 5.5 & 6.
{

   var arVersion = navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")
   var version = parseFloat(arVersion[1])
   if ((version >= 5.5) && (document.body.filters)) 
   {
      for(var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++)

      {
         var img = document.images[i]
         var imgName = img.src.toUpperCase()
         if (imgName.substring(imgName.length-3, imgName.length) == "PNG")
         {
            var imgID = (img.id) ? "id='" + img.id + "' " : ""

            var imgClass = (img.className) ? "class='" + img.className + "' " : ""
            var imgTitle = (img.title) ? "title='" + img.title + "' " : "title='" + img.alt + "' "

            var imgStyle = "display:inline-block;" + img.style.cssText 
            if (img.align == "left") imgStyle = "float:left;" + imgStyle
            if (img.align == "right") imgStyle = "float:right;" + imgStyle

            if (img.parentElement.href) imgStyle = "cursor:hand;" + imgStyle
            var strNewHTML = "<span " + imgID + imgClass + imgTitle
            + " style=\"" + "width:" + img.width + "px; height:" + img.height + "px;" + imgStyle + ";"

            + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"
            + "(src=\'" + img.src + "\', sizingMethod='scale');\"></span>" 
            img.outerHTML = strNewHTML

            i = i-1
         }
      }
   }    
}
window.attachEvent("onload", correctPNG);
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

try this hope it helps !!!

Comment: have tried this already...not working for me in case of image map with the IE fix on.

Comment: Well i think the script you have given is for correcting the Png image transparency in IE6 and below, the problem I am facing is related with using Image maps.

Comment: I am not having an issue with the png transparency in IE6...please go through the query again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution:

```
onclick="blur()" onfocus="navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ? blur() : null"
```

Comment: I tried many many (border, outline, ..) things, and only this worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional comments (more info [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)) + jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- 
    "old-ie" targets IE7 or less
    "ie8" targets IE8
    "ie" targets IE8+
-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="old-ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
...
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#link">
        <img src="/img/image.jpg" />
    </a>
</body>

</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// we first check if current browser is IE7 or older, than apply our "hack"

if (jQuery('html').is('.old-ie') === true) {
    jQuery('a').focus(function() { jQuery(this).blur(); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well found a way to solve this issue...which is probably not a good way to go for. By using js browser detection we can apply the IE fix as follows which will not cause problems to other browsers(FF in my case)

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('area')[0].onfocus = function () {this.blur();};
   }
```

Well please, if anyone finds a better solution then do post here. Thanks.

Comment: Abhidev, you could use conditional comments to detect if IE is running, more info [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). Going to add a new answer as a example.